# refreshing php variable with JS

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with refreshing PHP variable...
PHP variable after refreshing is still same - not refreshed

My little JS:

```
var reload = function() {
    var pred = <?php Echo json_encode(reload()); ?>;

    $(".reload").fadeIn("fast").text(pred);
    setTimeout(reload, 3000);
}
setTimeout(reload, 3000);
```

My PHP function:

```
function reload() {
        ForEach ($servers as $server) {
            $s = Explode(":", $server);
            $Data = $status->getStatus($s[0], $s[1]);
            If (!$Data) {} Else { $c1 = $c1 + $Data['Players']; } 
        }
        Return $c1; //Players returned 
}
```

If I joined the game after during this script the variable is the same as on beggining...
Nothing was changed. Why my variable isn't refreshing ? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for all help and sorry for my bad eng

Comment: PHP runs server-side.  It runs *before* the browser gets the page.  It generates the HTML/JavaScript page for the browser.  The only way to "reload" is to use AJAX.

Comment: Are you refreshing the page? PHP will only execute once per server request. You would need to set up an AJAX request to fetch the updated PHP variable.

Comment: Thanks all I am going to use ajax

Answer (score 3):

`reload()` is called only once: when the script executes for the first time. All PHP processing is completed on the server side before any output (including HTML and JavaScript) is sent to the browser.

When your JavaScript function executes, it re-uses the value that was produced by `reload()` the first time the script ran.

If you want to generate a new value via PHP, you will either need to refresh the page or create an AJAX call to fetch fresh data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var reload = function() {
    $.getJSON('reload.php', function(data){
         $(".reload").fadeIn("fast").text(data);
         setTimeout(reload, 3000);
    });
}

reload();
```

in your reload.php file

```
function reload() {
        ForEach ($servers as $server) {
            $s = Explode(":", $server);
            $Data = $status->getStatus($s[0], $s[1]);
            If (!$Data) {} Else { $c1 = $c1 + $Data['Players']; } 
        }
        Return $c1; //Players returned 
}

echo json_encode(reload());
```